# SQL Match employee intime (punch time) with employee shift

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure that retrieves employee daily summary intime - outtime:

```
SELECT ads.attendancesumid,
       ads.employeeid,
       ads.date,
       ads.day, -- month day number
       ads.intime,
       ads.outtime
       --employee shift intime and outtime
       ss.intime,
       ss.outtime
  FROM employee_attendance_daily_summary ads
  JOIN employee emp
    ON emp.employeeid = ads.employeeid
  JOIN setup_shift ss
    ON ss.shiftcode = emp.shiftcode
   AND DATEPART(dw, ads.date) = ss.day
 WHERE ads.employeeid = 4 -- just to filter one employee
```

The result of the query is something like this:

[image]

Each `day` is repeated **3 times** because table `setup_shift` (employee shifts) has:

> Monday to Sunday for 3 different shift types: **DAY**, **AFTERNOON** and **NIGHT**.

Here is the same info but with the shift type column:

[image]

> What I need is to **ONLY** get  1 row per day but with the closest employee shift depending on the `intime` and `outtime`.

So the desire result should looks like this:

[image]

Any clue on how to do this? Appreciate it in advance.

I have also these case where `intime` is `00:00:00` but `outtime` has a value:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

HERE IS THE SQL FIDDLE

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/791cb/7

Comment: What is the data type of the columns that look like times?

Comment: @Gordon the datatype is time(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ads.attendancesumid,
       ads.employeeid,
       ads.date,
       ads.day,
       ads.intime,
       ads.outtime,
       ss.intime,
       ss.outtime
  from employee_attendance_daily_summary ads
  join employee emp
    on emp.employeeid = ads.employeeid
  join setup_shift ss
    on ss.shiftcode = emp.shiftcode
   and datepart(dw, ads.date) = ss.day
 where ads.employeeid = 4
   and ((abs(datediff(hh,
                      cast(ads.intime as datetime),
                      cast(ss.intime as datetime))) between 0 and 2) or
       (ads.intime = '00:00:00' and
       ss.intime =
       (select min(x.intime)
            from setup_shift x
           where x.shiftcode = ss.shiftcode
             and x.intime > (select min(y.intime)
                               from setup_shift y
                              where y.shiftcode = x.shiftcode))))
```

Comment: This works great. I have some recordds where intime and outtime are 00:00:00 because no punch on that day. On those cases I should assign the DAY shift type. Any clue?

Comment: @VAAA see the last sql i edited in my answer. When the intime is 00:00:00 the query will show the 2nd earliest shift on setup_shift for the given shiftcode of the employee.

Comment: seems its working but now the filter employeeid = 4 is not working (im getting all employees :) ) its very close to the final solution

Comment: sound like its very close, the filter is working now but realize that when intime is for example: 23:01:04 I miss that record, maybe because the intime is greater than the shift intime.. i should get in that case the shift 23:00:00. Its very interesting your query!!

Comment: 23:01:04 should get matched with 23:00:00, it can be + or - 2 hours (rounded) because it's taking the absolute value. What about the out time for that record? The query is written in such a way that BOTH the in time and out time have to be within 2 hours of how the shift is coded.

Comment: @VAAA maybe the query should only evaluate the in time? Because employees might leave early?

Comment: The outtime for that record is 23:18:20. Thats the issue right?

Comment: @VAAA yes, try the updated sql. Hopefully it doesn't have adverse effects elsewhere though (ie. an employee who comes in late as opposed to leaving early)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57722/discussion-between-vaaa-and-brian-demilia).

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier if the times were in seconds after midnight, rather than in a `time`, `datetime`, or string format.  You can convert them using the formula:

```
select datepart(hour, intime) * 3600 + datepart(minute, intime) * 60 + datepart(second, intime)
```

(Part of this is just my own discomfort with all the nested functions needed to handle other data types.)

So, let me assume that you have a series of similar columns measured in seconds.  You can then approach this problem by taking the overlap with each shift and choosing the shift with the largest overlap.

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     ),
     ts as (
      select t.*,
             (datepart(hour, ads.intime) * 3600 + datepart(minute, ads.intime) * 60 + 
              datepart(second, ads.intime)
             ) as e_intimes,
             . . .
      from t
     ),
     tss as (
      select ts.*,
             (case when e_intimes >= s_outtimes then 0
                   when e_outtimes <= s_inttimes then 0
                   else (case when e_outtimes < s_outtimes then e_outtimes else s_outtimes end) -
                        (case when e_intimes > s_intimes then e_intimes else s_intimes end)
              end) as overlap
      from ts
     )
select ts.*
from (select ts.*,
             row_number() over (partition by employeeid, date
                                order by overlap desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from ts
     ) ts
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this man,I just take the minimum time difference of the each set `datediff(mi,intime,shift_intime)`

```
Select * from 
(select 
row_number() over(partition by employeeid 
                   order by datediff(mi,intime,shift_intime) asc) as id,
attendance,employeeid,date,day,intime,outime,shiftintime,shiftoutime from table
 )
where id=1
```